# On Android emulator, trying to load a webview i get net::err_cache_miss

Tags: android, webview

I tried the example shown on Android developers website to show a webpage on a WebView component without success. The emulator shows the following error:

> Webpage not available the webpage at http://developer.android.com
>   could not be loaded because: net::ERR_CHACHE_MISS

I could not find any solution so far, even after looking on other threads on the web. I have also tried different links.
I do not know if could be helpful in understanding the cause of this error, but the emulator is Nexus 4 API 21 with Android 5.0.1. I am using Android Studio 1.0.

The code is the same of the example:

```
In MainActivity.java:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);           
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
}
```

In AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
.....
```

And in the view I have added the same code of the example

Example is on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 43):

Exactly, It has occured to me once and the solution was to put the following line: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

before the `<application` tag in the manifest.xml file.

Either that line is missing or it's misplaced (eg. at the end of the `</manifest>` tag.

Comment: I tried this solution of adding the permission and it worked. Thank you @samuele

Comment: The user permission was there, but in the wrong place, inside the activity tag. I suppose it was the reason why it was not working.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone else encounters this problem and since there isn't an answer here I thought I'd provide one.

For me it turned out to simply be the order the tags were in the manifest file. The user-permission element needs to appear before the application element. I just put it directly under the manifest element at the top and that seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: we have to build you'r statue in center of our capital! i have almost tested hundreds of solutions but none of theme worked.yaaay!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I fixed with
    
inside the activity, like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Because I build inside the main activity the webView....
I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the place of  tag matters here.
For example, this doesn't work:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </activity>
```

But below code works perfectly.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include these Permissions in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: A bit more in the way of an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @SteveHeim : Are you running your app on Emulator or on Real Device?

Comment: it's not for me, I was just reviewing first-time answers : ). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please paste  the following outside the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```